# Using preg_match to discover and validate types of links embedded in html

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, strpos

I have implemented a function to validate .edu domains. This is how I am doing it:

```
if( preg_match('/edu/', $matches[0])==FALSE )
    return FALSE;
return TRUE;
```

Now I want to skip those urls as well that point to some documents such as .pdf and .doc.

For this, the following code should have worked but is not:

```
if( preg_match('/edu/', $matches[0])==FALSE || preg_match('/pdf/i', $matches[0])!=FALSE || preg_match('/doc/i', $matches[0]!=FALSE))
        return FALSE;
return TRUE;
```

Where am I wrong in this regard?
Moreover, how will I implement preg_match in such a way that it has a list of document types to check in a url string. If a certain type of document is found, it should return false. In other words, I want to provide a list (an array maybe) of various document types as $pattern to find in a url.

> Note:
>   matches[0] contains the whole url string.
>   eg: http://www.nust.edu.pk/Documents/pdf/NNBS_Form.pdf

The code for the function:

```
public function validateEduDomain($url) {
    // get host name from URL
    preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i', $url, $matches);
    $host = $matches[1];

    // get last two segments of host name
    preg_match('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/', $host, $matches);

    if( preg_match('/edu/', $matches[0])!=FALSE && (preg_match('/pdf/i', $matches[0])==FALSE || preg_match('/doc/i', $matches[0]==FALSE)))      
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Is http://www.education.vic.gov.au/ a valid match?

Comment: @Johnsyweb yes the function returns true which means it validates the url. Though I thought I had implemented it to return FALSE in the above case. Nice question to point out and thanks. I think changing it to .edu should work.

Comment: Changing it to `.edu` won't fix it. `http://www.education.vic.gov.au/` contains `.edu`.

Comment: How should I do that such that preg_match tries to find exactly .edu sub string??

Comment: I'm still unclear as to what constitutes a "valid" domain are the following valid: `net.educause.edu`, `harvard.edu` `www.unimelb.edu.au`, `edu.example.com`, `mail.edu.example.com`?

Comment: Yes all are valid domains. But if net.educause.edu had been net.educause.com, it would have been invalid.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6282/discussion-between-spoilt-and-johnsyweb)

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions? You're looking for a fixed substring; a simple linear search is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder why are you making everything so complicated, and also noticed you have $$matches[0] instead of $matches[0]. The regexes you want is:

```
if( preg_match('/^https?:\/\/[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.edu/i', $matches[0]) && !preg_match('/\.(pdf)|(doc)$/i', $matches[0]) ) {
    // do something here...
}
```

Comment: Your code is not working, particularly talking about the second part that validates the document type. The function is still returning true on those urls that do contain .pdf and .doc substrings.

I know that this is not complicated but I am not getting the format and arguments that preg_match receives in $pattern. I mean all those /\.^ etc. Please help.

Comment: tested it on regex tester before posting, i'm pretty sure it works

Comment: Then let me try and debug once again.

Comment: Can you please check out the link and tell me where I am going wrong. I still don't get it.
http://ideone.com/1OHvz

Comment: umm I guess you should remove the beginning part (everything in function before the if( statement, because that's what I have already included in the regex above :)

Comment: and of course put $url instead of $matches[0] in preg_match()

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. BeatMasta. The crawler is working as anticipated. Thanks once more.

I wonder why a single line of code can render a thousand line of code useless.

What actually was happening was that the crawler was retrieving a lot of noisy data from pdfs while scrapping the html. This was generating invalid MySQL queries and as a result the crawler was crashing when some very large pdf files were retrieved. The most common error was "MySQL server has gone away".

I am indebted to you for this help.

Comment: by the way, that's because I sometimes dislike PHP too much: it's not always that you can do elegant line of code which will deny many lines .. the best example of that is - you can't array element directly after anything else, e.g. "mysql_fetch_array($result)[0]", that's what you can do in good OOP languages like Python or JS...

Comment: @Spoilt: "I wonder why a single line of code can render a thousand line of code useless", usually because it is trying to do too many things and is not unit-tested.

Comment: Well what do you think? Which language would have been more appropriate for implementing a web crawler?? And I have found php to be a lot lot slower than Java and C++ and obviously its not robust.

Comment: Well you are right. This was not unit tested. Actually I was relatively new to php. It took me about 8-9 days to learn the language and create a crawler side by side with no background knowledge of server-side programming. I have done unit testing in Java but I don't know the procedure for php and since time was short for the project, I skipped that part. By the way I am using Eclipse PDT for php development and any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: umm haven't seen any project in java that is really lightweight or works faster than my php code))) c++ !MUST! be faster because it's compilable and it's grandfather of many common languages) Python is nowadays one of the best solutions for web backend. I started using it recently also for my master thesis... What refers to IDE, I personally use Jetbrains PHPStorm (it's proprietary soft and must be cracked :D), which is heavy a bit, but helps a lot providing big functionality, so you don't have to worry about many things

Comment: This renders [`"http://edu.example.com/Documents/pdf/NNBS_Form.rtf"` as invalid](http://ideone.com/47SP6). As Spoilt adds more document types ('.rtf', 'docx', ...), this will quickly become less maintainable.

Comment: I thought that if it doesn't containt TLD .edu than it must not be correct, must it?

Comment: According to the comments under the question, `edu.example.com` is a valid edu domain.

Comment: So what will be the best alternative @Johnsyweb??

Comment: oks, then you can change last part of the first regex from \.edu/i to (\.?edu)|(edu\.?)/i

Comment: @Spoilt: I would submit that [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8691300/78845) is a better alternative.

Comment: As I am a learner, I welcome comments from all the members of this community as there are a lot of things one cannot learn from books.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, not in any case, as you can not always know everything by just splitting string.. Maybe that's a better solution for speed performance, I would agree if you stated that regex speed in PHP sucks :) but if it comes to test whether the "edu" is STRICTLY in the beginning or at the end of the url part - I'd prefer regex here :)

Answer (score 1):

You can see if a file extension matches with something like:

```
 preg_match('/\.php$/i', $string);
```

Also, why are you using the double dollar sign for the 2nd and 3rd usages of $matches[0]?

Comment: Well i mistyped it here in the post

Comment: And how can I pass a complete array of document types to preg_match??

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, something like this can help: http://ideone.com/XOEiU

```
function validate_path($url) {
    $url_parts = parse_url($url);
    $path_info = pathinfo($url_parts['path']);

    return preg_match('/\\.edu(?:\\.|$)/', $url_parts['host']) && in_array($path_info['extension'], array('pdf', 'doc', 'docx'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a regular expression for this:

```
function is_edu_domain($url)
{
    $parsed = parse_url($url);
    $parts = explode('.', $parsed['host']);
    return in_array('edu', $parts, TRUE);
}
```

This matches the domains you specified in your comments.

For the file extensions I would have a separate function that is easier to maintain:

```
function is_unwanted_file_extension($url)
{
    $path = pathinfo($url);
    $extension = strtolower($path['extension']);
    $unwanted_extensions = explode(',', 'pdf,doc');
    return in_array($extension, $unwanted_extensions, TRUE);
}
```

You can combine the two:

```
function is_url_from_edu_and_wanted($url)
{
    return is_edu_domain($url) and !is_unwanted_file_extension($url);
}
```

Much more readable and maintainable then regular expressions but note that I have optimised for these things and not for speed.

Comment: `if (substr($var, -4) === '.edu') ...`
You don't need arrays for this and nor will it show whether edu is in the tlds.

Comment: @Walf: According to the comments `net.educause.edu`, `harvard.edu` `www.unimelb.edu.au`, `edu.example.com` and `mail.edu.example.com` are all valid domains and your `substr()` approach won't work (we're not just interested in the TLD). The down-vote is therefore unjustified.

Comment: I didn't say that one line was the solution, I just said you don't need arrays. Your example will still return false positives on input like `edu.ponzischeme.com`.

Comment: @Walf: If `edu.example.com` is a valid educational domain, as per the comments on the original question, then I don't see why `edu.ponzischeme.com` would be considered a *false* positive. My reasoning for taking this approach is for future readability and maintainability. Arrays may not be strictly necessary but they are a perfectly valid approach to solving this problem.